# How to set image in imageview while testing with espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have used third party library in my sign up form for selecting image from gallery. My signup form works fine. Now I want to test it using espresso.The biggest problem that I am facing right now is how to set profile photo's imageview while testing ?

Comment: Which library do you use. What is exactly the Problem? What did you try so far? How is the profile image set when not in tests?

Answer (score 1):

You should use [espresso-intents](https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/intents/) to detect that intent from the camera roll and set a picture.

Here you have the method I use:

```
public static void simulatePictureFromCameraRoll(Uri pictureUri) throws  Exception {
    Exception returnException = null;
    Intent resultData = new Intent();

    resultData.setData(pictureUri);

    Intents.init();
    try {
        Matcher<Intent> expectedIntent = hasAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        intending(expectedIntent).respondWith(new Instrumentation.ActivityResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultData));
        onView(withId(R.id.lytProfImageChooseFromLibrary)).perform(click());
        intended(expectedIntent);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        returnException = e;
    }
    finally {
        Intents.release();
    }

    if (returnException != null) {
        throw returnException;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I capture the exception because it's important to ensure that the Intents.release is done or you can have problems if your tests call the Intents.init multiple times